# To keep modified data on view on auto refresh of view data in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, view

I am working on an angular 2 application. I came across the following scenario:
The data to be shown on view is coming from API. There are some fields which can be modified from view and then saved using API calls. There is functionality of auto refresh every 30 seconds(API call to update the view with latest data). Now suppose the user has modified the editable fields and before submitting for save, the page is auto refreshed and the changes made by the user is lost. 
What I want, is to save the data changed by the user so that there is no need to modify it again after auto refresh.
Suggest some efficient way to implement it.

Comment: Auto save before auto refresh?

Comment: Try caching the values entered by the user on to a local variables and once the auto refresh is complete update editable fields with the values of the local variables

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable in your component for flag that user something changed. Your code will look like this:

```
export class YourComponent implements DoCheck{
  isUserChanged: boolean;

  // ngDoCheck will fire every time when change detection of Angular will fire
  ngDoCheck() {
    this.isUserChanged = true;
    // make isUserChanged to false when you need to do it.
  }
}
```

when isUserChanged will be true then you will not update your view with data.
Hope it will help